# How and where does py.test find fixtures

Tags: python, fixtures, pytest

Where and how  does  py.test  look for  fixtures? I  have  the  same code  in 2 files in the  same  folder. When I  delete conftest.py, cmdopt  cannot  be  found running test_conf.py (also in same  folder.  Why  is  sonoftest.py not  searched?

```
# content of test_sample.py
def test_answer(cmdopt):
    if cmdopt == "type1":
        print ("first")
    elif cmdopt == "type2":
        print ("second")
    assert 0 # to see what was printed
```

## content of conftest.py

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1",
        help="my option: type1 or type2")

@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--cmdopt")
```

## content of sonoftest.py

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1",
        help="my option: type1 or type2")

@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--cmdopt")
```

The  docs say

http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-function

> 1. pytest finds  the test_ehlo  because of the test_ prefix. The test function needs a function argument named smtp. A matching fixture
>      function is discovered by looking for a fixture-marked function named
>      smtp.
> 2. smtp() is called to create an instance.
> 3. test_ehlo() is called and fails in the last line of the test function.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

py.test will import `conftest.py` and all Python files that match the `python_files` pattern, by default `test_*.py`.  If you have a test fixture, you need to include or import it from `conftest.py` or from the test files that depend on it:

```
from sonoftest import pytest_addoption, cmdopt
```

Comment: By some reason, if you are using Pycharm it detects the import of the fixture as unused (At least in version 2021.2.3). Anyway if you remove the fixture import it stops working.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the order and where py.test looks for fixtures (and tests) (taken from [here](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup)):

py.test loads plugin modules at tool startup in the following way:

> 1. by loading all builtin plugins
> 2. by loading all plugins registered through setuptools entry points.
> 3. by pre-scanning the command line for the `-p name` option and loading the specified plugin before actual command line parsing.
> 4. by loading all `conftest.py` files as inferred by the command line invocation (test files and all of its parent directories). Note that
>      `conftest.py` files from sub directories are by default not loaded at
>      tool startup.
> 5. by recursively loading all plugins specified by the pytest_plugins variable in `conftest.py` files

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and spent a lot of time to find out a simple solution, this example is for others that have a similar situation as I had.

- conftest.py:

```py
import pytest

pytest_plugins = [
 "some_package.sonoftest"
]

def pytest_addoption(parser):
  parser.addoption("--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1",
      help="my option: type1 or type2")

@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
  return request.config.getoption("--cmdopt")
```

- some_package/sonoftest.py:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def sono_cmdopt(request):
  return request.config.getoption("--cmdopt")
```

- some_package/test_sample.py

```py
def test_answer1(cmdopt):
  if cmdopt == "type1":
      print ("first")
  elif cmdopt == "type2":
      print ("second")
  assert 0 # to see what was printed

def test_answer2(sono_cmdopt):
  if sono_cmdopt == "type1":
      print ("first")
  elif sono_cmdopt == "type2":
      print ("second")
  assert 0 # to see what was printed
```

You can find a similar example here: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3039#issuecomment-464489204
and other here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736376/6655459

Description from official pytest documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=pytest_plugins#pytest-plugins

> As a note that the respective directories referred to in 
>   `some_package.test_sample"` need to have `__init__.py` files for the plugins to be loaded by `pytest`