# How do I get py.test to recognize conftest.py in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, pytest

So, I just lost a *day* trying to find out why `py.test` isn't executing my autouse, session-scoped setup and teardown fixtures. In the end I stumbled over (hat tip to [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13686206/599884)!) this little tidbit in the [plugins documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup):

> Note that conftest.py files from sub directories are by default not loaded at tool startup.

In my project, I got my py.test files (`conftest.py` and tests files) in a `tests/` subdirectory, which seems like a pretty standard setup. If I run `py.test` in the tests directory, everything runs correctly. If I run `py.test` in the project root directory, the tests still run, but the **setup/teardown routines never get executed**.

Questions:

- What's the "canonical" way to enable users to correctly run tests from the project root dir? Putting `conftest.py` in the root directory feels strange to me, cause I feel all tests-related files should remain in the `tests` subdirectory.
- Why (design-wise) aren't `conftest.py`'s in subdirectories not loaded by default? I find this behaviour curious to say the least, considering that *tests* in subdirectories are discovered by default, so there seems to be very little additional effort involved in finding conftest files, too.
- Lastly, how can I have `conftest.py` in subdirectories load (i.e. change away from the default)? I couldn't find this in the docs. I'd like to avoid additional console
  arguments if possible, so can I put anything in a config file or
  whatnot?

Any insight and tips are much appreciated, I feel that I lost/wasted wayy to much time diagnosing this when I could have written tests for my project. :-(

Minimal example:

```
# content of tests/conftest.py
# adapted from http://pytest.org/latest/example/special.html
import pytest
def tear_down():
    print "\nTEARDOWN after all tests"

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def set_up(request):
    print "\nSETUP before all tests"
    request.addfinalizer(tear_down)
```

test file:

```
# content of tests/test_module.py
class TestClassA:
    def test_1(self):
        print "test A1 called"
    def test_2(self):
        print "test A2 called"

class TestClassB:
    def test_1(self):
        print "test B1 called"
```

Console output:

```
pytest_experiment$ py.test -s
======================================================== test session starts =========================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.2
plugins: cov
collected 3 items 

tests/test_module.py test A1 called
.test A2 called
.test B1 called
.

====================================================== 3 passed in 0.02 seconds ======================================================
pytest_experiment$ cd tests/
pytest_experiment/tests$ py.test -s
======================================================== test session starts =========================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- pytest-2.3.2
plugins: cov
collected 3 items 

test_module.py 
SETUP before all tests
test A1 called
.test A2 called
.test B1 called
.
TEARDOWN after all tests


====================================================== 3 passed in 0.02 seconds ======================================================
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://ascii.io/a/5263

Comment: yes, in the meantime I found out that this was an already fixed bug all along.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some help on the #pylib IRC channel, it turns out that this was a bug that has been fixed in [py.test 2.3.4](http://pytest.org/latest/changelog.html#changes-between-2-3-3-and-2-3-4).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have `conftest.py` in `tests/` but it has no effect.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius probably best to report a bug against pytest: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues

Comment: Actually, in my case it's a bit different. Rather than having `test/` at the root of my package/project,  I have it in the folder for the (lone) module in my package. Should it not be there? My understanding was that each module could have its own `test/` folder (and test placed in such folders do run). Is not the case. Should I have a `test/` folder (or my `conftest.py`) at the root of my package?

Comment: I have a [follow up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33964355/656912) about how to organize tests.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more than pointing to the pytest docs, and you have obviously already found those.