# How to I organize my pytest tests if I'm not distributing them with my package?

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, software-distribution

As [suggested in the pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules), I have set up my package with the intent not *not* distributing my tests along with my package:

```
setup.py
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    mypkg/
      appmodule.py  
tests/
    test_app.py
    ...
```

but I am confused about how to ensure that these tests will run correctly when present (e.g. on Travis CI, or in clones of the project directory).

I want the imports in my test scripts to apply to the source in the adjacent `mypkg/` directory (and not to any `mypkg` that might be installed in `site-packages`), but I'm getting errors that puzzle me.

If I follow the advice in the `pytest` documentation and don't put an `__init__.py` in `tests/` then with

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from mypkg.appmodule import *
```

I get

> ImportError: No module named mypkg.appmodule

while with

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from ..mypkg.appmodule import *
```

I get

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

And if I ignore the documentation and include an `__init__.py`, then with the latter I get

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Only by including an `__init__.py` and using

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from mypkg.appmodule import *
```

will my tests run. But it isn't clear to me that this will import the source from the adjacent `mypkg/` directory if a `mypkg` is installed in `site-packages`.

What is the correct way to organize my `pytest` tests so that they are separate from — and not distributed with — my projects source, but always import the adjacent source, and not version of the package that is installed elswehere?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is just that python can't find your appmodule when you ask for it to look in the mypkg directory where it doesn't exist.

You've set the directories up correctly with:

```
setup.py
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    mypkg/
        appmodule.py  
tests/
    test_app.py
    ...
```

But since you've created another mypkg/ subdirectory to house your appmodule.py, you'll need to place __init__.py in that subdirectory for an import to work. The call would also be changed to:

```
from mypkg.mypkg.appmodule import *
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, so: the instructions are misleading in this case.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius why do you say that? I mean, the documentation says to use `mypkg/appmodule.py`.

Comment: I mean the `pytest` docs. They say not to have an `__init__.py` in `tests/`, which is (as you say) the only way this works.

Comment: In this instance I meant that your mypkg/mypkg sub directory needs to contain \__init__.py as well. That's why python's throwing "ImportError: No module named mypkg.appmodule" at you -- because appmodule.py doesn't exist in the top mypkg/ directory. The pytest documentation you followed didn't account for the mypkg/mypkg sub-directory you created.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I actually had to just put a `__init__.py` in the `tests/` directory and called it a day.

Comment: @trendsetter37: Yes, that's clear. The question is why that contradicts the documentation.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius [here](https://github.com/trendsetter37/md5-checker/tree/dev) is an example of conftest.py working. Also note that I added `packages=find_packages(exclude=['contrib', 'docs', 'tests*']),` in my setup.py to prevent distribution of my test folder.