# Pytest "Error: could not load path/to/conftest.py"

Tags: pytest

I get the following error when I try to run `pytest repo/tests/test_file.py`:

```
$ pytest repo/tests/test_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marlo/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 329, in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
KeyError: local('/Users/marlo/repo/tests/test_file.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marlo/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 329, in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
KeyError: local('/Users/marlo/repo/tests')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marlo/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 362, in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
KeyError: local('/Users/marlo/repo/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marlo/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 368, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "/Users/marlo/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 686, in pyimport
    raise self.ImportMismatchError(modname, modfile, self)
py._path.local.LocalPath.ImportMismatchError: ('conftest', '/home/venvuser/venv/conftest.py', local('/Users/marlo/repo/conftest.py'))
ERROR: could not load /Users/marlo/repo/conftest.py
```

My repo structure is

```
lib/
    -tests/
        -test_file.py
app/
    -test_settings.py
pytest.ini
conftest.py
...
```

Other people have run this code fine, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964355/how-to-i-organize-my-pytest-tests-if-im-not-distributing-them-with-my-package) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558666/how-do-i-get-py-test-to-recognize-conftest-py-in-a-subdirectory)), my structure is good and I am not missing any files.  I can only conclude that something about my computer or project set-up is not right.  If you have any suggestions or insights that I may be missing, please send them my way!

-------------------------------MORE DETAILS------------------------------

**test_file.py**:

```
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

**pytest.ini**:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = app.test_settings
python_files = tests.py test_* *_tests.py *test.py
```

Comment: 1. Assuming the root dir containing `lib/`, `app/` and `conftest.py` is named `repo` - does the file `repo/tests/test_file.py` exist? 2. Run `cd repo; pytest --collect-only`, are all the tests found correctly? 3. What is the file `/home/venvuser/venv/conftest.py` and why is it loaded? It even belongs to another user than you, is that deliberate? Check if your `sys.path` maybe contains some unwanted entries.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you for your suggestions!  It turned out that I had a docker container with different filepaths that was interfering with pytest.

Comment: I added an empty `__init__.py` in `app/tests` and it worked.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I have docker as well as running pytest outside of docker too, and for me a much lower-impact fix whenever this crops up is to delete all the compiled python files

`find . -name \*.pyc -delete`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried this as well and it wasn't enough for my case.  But if more people upvote it, I'll accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Was enough for my case (but I did it with `git clean -dfqx` though).

Comment: @JulienPalard You should warn people about using that command. It deletes a lot more the .pyc files

Comment: I'm not sure how it deletes more than .pyc files?  But the 'git clean -dfqx' command definitely seems cleaner.  I'm not in a position to test this right now (not using docker these days) but if somebody else confirms I'll clean this answer up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I'll answer in case others have the same issue:

I didn't even take into consideration that I had a docker container (of the same app) in the repo directory and, although I was not running the docker container, it was influencing the filepaths somehow.

To fix this:

1. I re-cloned the repo from the remote source into a new folder so that nothing from the old repo could "contaminate" it.
2. Updated my virtual environment with the .yml specifications of the clean repo

```
    $ conda env update --name project --file project.yml
```

3. My project uses a postgres database, so I dropped it and created a new one

```
    $ dropdb projectdb
    $ createdb projectdb
```

4. Since my project uses mongo, I also dropped that database

```
    $ mongo projectdb --eval "db.dropDatabase()"
```

5. Installed a clean `pytest`

```
    $ pip uninstall pytest
    $ pip install pytest
```

...and voilà!  I could run pytest.

Many thanks to @hoefling and others who helped me debug.

Answer (score 1):

I was running docker as well, but it seems my problem was different.
I was using an old version of pytest:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-3.7.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
```

which stopped working after my ubuntu image was pulling python 3.10 by default.
my solution was to update (and fix) the dockerfile image to use:

```
FROM python:3.10
```

instead of `python:latest`, and update the pytest version as well.