# pytest fixtures in a separate directory

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I'm looking to create a pytest structure where I can separate the fixtures from the tests completely. The reason for this separation is that I want to include the fixtures directory as an external item in subversion and share it between multiple projects.

**tree of desired structure**

```
project
|   conftest.py
|
+---fixtures
|       __init__.py
|       conftest.py
|       fixture_cifs.py
|       fixture_ftp.py
|       fixture_service.py
|
\---tests
    |   test_sometest1.py
    |   test_sometest2.py
    |
    \---configurations
            sometest1.conf
            sometest2.conf
```

I want to implement the functionality for each fixture in a separate file in order to avoid a single huge `conftest.py`. `conftest.py` would just include wrappers to return an instance of each fixture annotated with `@pytest.fixture`. There is no problem using a fixture together with a test when the `conftest.py`, `fixture_*.py` and `test_*.py` files are all in the same directory.

However, when the fixtures are separated in a subdirectory I get an error from pytest `fixture 'cifs' not found`, `available fixtures: ...`. I haven't found any documentation explaining how to place fixtures outside of `test_*.py` or the `conftest.py` adjacent to `test_*.py`, but nothing to indicate that this shouldn't work either.

**How can I place fixtures in their own subdirectory when using pytest?**

Answer (score 42):

Please add the following in your **conftest.py**

```py
  import pytest

  pytest_plugins = [
   "fixtures.conftest",
   "fixtures.fixture_cifs",
   "fixtures.fixture_ftp",
   "fixtures.fixture_service"
  ]
```

This ensures that all fixtures declared under `fixtures/` will be found by `pytest`

> As a note that the respective directories referred to in 
>   `fixtures.conftest"` need to have `__init__.py` files for the plugins to be loaded by `pytest`

A similar case can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736237/6655459

Answer (score 2):

read [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules) how structure your test.

Your fixture directory doesn't seem to be part of a package (project does not have `__init__.py` so cannot be imported as `project.fixtures` either as `fixtures` as it is not in the path.
You can add required dirs in the path in your `tests/conftest.py` (`sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir, "fixtures"))` or `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)` depending how how you want import your modules.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing your fixtures in `project/conftest.py`
if that is what you mean by *"wrappers to return an instance"*

Answer (score 0):

For when I inevitably come back to this question: **you can import fixtures in different files** (even files which would not typically access the fixture) and the tests will pick it up appropriately!