# How to access a fixture in my test class from any directory in pytest?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

[image][image]I need your kind help to access a feature from any directory to my test class in pytest.

I can create the fixture inside the test class itself and call without any problem and it works fine too. I also know that creating the desired fixture in conftest.py will also help me.

However, my specific requirement is, I need to define a fixture in a separate directory and call in my test class(es).

Please refer to the screenshots, to understand my requirement exactly.

In `data/testdata/InvalidLoginData.py`, I have defined the fixture.

I want to use the data in `test_invalidlogin.py`

Could you please advise -

1. If I am doing any mistake?
2. Is it possible in pytest?

Edit: I checked [this](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-datadir/) and [this](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-datafiles/), but they do not suit my requirement.

Comment: Add those images as well, without them its difficult to get how directory looks like

Comment: Added the images, not sure how they got deleted earlier. sorry.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567306/pytest-fixtures-in-a-separate-directory

Comment: @DV82XL - Yes this has helped me and I am able to call the fixture from outside my test directory.